# Computing pairwise distances in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a dataset in Hive that looks like this:

```
   Point  Latitude  Longitude
       A      40.3       74.8
       B      12.5      -45.1
       C     -32.7       87.6
       D      23.9      -67.2
     ...       ...        ...
```

How can I obtain a matrix with the distance of each point from all the other points? That is, the distances AB, AC, AD, BC, BD, CD and so forth. If it is easier to have the output in a linear format, that is fine as well. I want to be able to do this all using Hive Query Language.

Edit: The data contains hundreds of thousands of rows. In the end I want to be able to identify all points within a certain radius of a given point. So if there a way to reduce the number of calculations by first filtering out points or using some approximation, I am open to that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution for this can be that you do a join of the same on itself without any condition. The output would be something like this

```
      query1  query1      query1    query2 query2     query2
      Point  Latitude  Longitude    Point  Latitude  Longitude
       A      40.3       74.8       A      40.3       74.8
       A      40.3       74.8       B      12.5      -45.1
       A      40.3       74.8       C     -32.7       87.6
       A      40.3       74.8       D      23.9      -67.2
      ...
```

Use the above output as a subquery and compute the distances between the points. Basically a concat of query1.Point and query2.point would give you the pair and the distance function on latitude and longitudes will give you the distance between them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, Amar. I will try this out and let you know how it goes.